# Reconstruct a matrix from given eigenvalues

Tags: numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra

I wanted to know how can I reconstruct a matrix **just from its given eigenvalues**.
I'm really sorry, cause after working on it for 3 days, I haven't any idea about how to do this, therefore I haven't anything useful to share.

**NOTE:**
I know how to reconstruct a matrix from given eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

Answer (score 3):

No, any matrix $U^{-1}AU$ has the same eigenvalues and Jordan normal form as $A$. In fact, one can say that the Jordan normal form is the standard representative of these classes of conjugate matrices.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes when you try hard to prove something and fail, it's because what you're trying to prove isn't true, and it's time to look for a counterexample. The matrices 
$$
1 \quad x \\
0 \quad 2
$$
all have the same eigenvalues, whatever the value of $x$.

The OP's comment below suggests that he'd be happy with *some* matrix with prescribed eigenvalues. For that, just put them on the diagonal, with zero elsewhere.

Comment: but I think i fount the answer and I'll soon post it here, first we have to form a monic polynomial with the eigenvalues and then we have to form a companion matrix for this polynomial, and I'm not sure about the next part, I think i might solve the problem till tomorrow, I'll inform you if anything changed.

Comment: forgot something, we form the monic polynomial in order to form a characteristic polynomial of the matrix which we are trying to reconstruct!

Comment: by the way @user247327's answer is correct too.

Comment: @JohnFord All the answers here are correct. You should accept one, and vote up any you find useful (including the one you accept).

Answer (score 1):

First form D, the diagonal matrix having the given eigenvalues on the diagonal.  Then $M= BDB^{-1}!$, where B is any invertible matrix, has the same eigenvalues.

(If you are given the eigenvalues **and** corresponding eigenvectors, in a specific order, then there is a unique such matrix- do as above, taking the columns of B to be the eigenvectors.)